# How do you prevent a property from being serialized when loading an object from the raven db document store

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I am loading an object from the document store as such and was wondering if there was a way to exclude a property from being serialized. When being saved the property is not serialized to the document store using the JsonIgnore attribute but when it's loaded the property getter is called.

```
[Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
public Stream MessageStream { get; set; }

using (var sess = store.OpenSession())
{
    var savedMsg = sess.Load<MessageEnvelope>("acc02a0c-8c00-44e8-a3cf-cb732714aabf");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your [ObjectCreationHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm). The `MessageStream` in your deserialized object will have value `default(Stream)`, which the serialize checks for and replaces if needed.

Change it from Auto to Replace if you don't want to see this behavior.

Comment: @Alex I was being too rhetorical, this is the answer.

Comment: ok, it kinda didn't read like that. Just checked the link & I'll remove my comment

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of this enumeration? Is this in the constructor of an attribute? Never mind I see it's used in the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty attrib. Thanks!